# How do you get the amount of shares issued by a ERC-4626 deposit?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin

You can call `previewDeposits` but from what I've read it's not actually guaranteed that the amount of shares issued will be equal to the value returned be `previewDeposit`.

There doesn't seem to be any other function to query the amount of shares a user owns.

Is it safe to assume the amount of tokens a user will receive is atleast the value returned by `previewDeposits`?

I'm using the [Open Zeppelin implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC4626.sol).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can simply call the balance of the vault shares the user has.